# Onsen UI & AngularJS: Show / trigger native Datepicker after click

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I use a input to edit a date. 
Initially, The input is hidden and is replaced by a div with the birthdate and a edit-Icon. After a click on the div, the input will be shown. Everything works fine, but how can trigger / click programmatically on the input to show the **native** date wheel in iOS? Thank you for your tips

Currently the user has to click on the input. With the following JS, I get an error: *Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!*

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-birthdate" ng-click="openBirthdate(); bEdit = !bEdit" ng-hide="bEdit">{{ birthDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }} <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-profile-edit"></i></div>
<div class="profile-birthdate"  ng-click="bEdit = !bEdit" ng-show="bEdit"><input id="birthDateChange" type="date" ng-model="birthDate"> <i class="fa fa-check fa-profile-edit"></i></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.openBirthdate = function () {
      $timeout(function() {
          angular.element('#birthDateChange').trigger('click');
       }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to use **jQuery** instead of **jqLite**

In order to keep Angular small, Angular implements only a subset of the selectors in jqLite. This error occurs when a jqLite instance is invoked with a selector other than this subset.

Try including  jQuery before AngularJS, if you have still the same issue, try the AngularJS shim in this way:

```
shim: {
   angular: {
       deps: ['jquery'],
       exports: "angular"
   },
},
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That´s it! Thank you Andi